# Automatically flag unused structure members in C

Tags: c, clang, abstract-syntax-tree, static-analysis

I need a tool to automatically flag unused *structure members* in a C codebase. My definition of "unused" is simple - if the structure member definition is removed from the code, and the code compiles successfully, then the structure member is declared unused. The question is - how can this be done in an automated way? (speed isn't too much of concern as the codebase is small).

The existing stack overflow articles on this topic seem to hint that there is no existing static analysis tool that can do this today. On the other hand, given the modularity of Clang, I feel that this should be doable with AST manipulation. Let's take a single file, for example. What I would like to do is the following (this can be later generalized to a set of source files in the codebase):

1. Generate AST from C code.
2. Recursively visit all structure field defintions and *remove* them one-by-one. We can keep a "seen" dictionary to ensure we don't remove already seen field definition nodes.

   - Filter out field definitions to only those that are present in the codebase to analyzed (to avoid definitions in standard libraries, for example).
3. Compile the code.
4. If the code compiles successfully, then the corresponding field declaration is unused and is flagged.
5. Proceed to #1.

The keyword above is *remove*. How can I *remove* a field definition? There seems to be two ways using Clang.

1. At a source level, we can remove the field declaration using Clang Rewriter (there is a "RemoveText(SourceRange)" option). But, I don't know if this will work all the time (ex: for structures are autogenerated using MACRO expansion).
2. Delete the field declaration node from AST, and then "re-compile" the AST (whatever that means).

Among the above two options, #1 seems hacky - you'll need to create a copy of the source file, re-write it after a field definition is removed, and then re-compile the modified source. And, I am not sure how well it will work when there are complex MACROS involved for generating structure field definitions.

#2 seems clean, but from Googling, there seems to be no such thing as "deleting a AST node" (it is immutable). Please correct me if I am wrong. Even if I succeed in this, how I proceed from this point to re-evaluate the AST for missing references to structure fields? ("the compilation" step).

Any sugesstions appreciated (thanks in advance!). I've already have some initial success with #1 approach above, but I feel that this isn't the right direction.

Comment: Might not be true for your code, but in general un-referenced structure members are not that uncommon, for alignment purposes. E.g. you might be reading data from a file into a struct, with members that are there in the file but which your application doesn't care about.

Comment: Comment them out, and try to recompile?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Yes, I *expect* that there will be false alarms, and someone will need to sort through them and handle the ones that seem genuine - just wanted a way to automate this process of flagging them.

Comment: @wildplasser - I would like automate this. Doing this manually will be too much effort and time.

Answer (score 3):

[cppcheck](http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/) can do this. For example:

```cpp
// test.cpp
struct Struct
{
    int used;
    int unused;
};

int main()
{
    Struct s;
    s.used = 0;
    return s.used;
}
```

```
$ cppcheck test.cpp --enable=all
Checking test.cpp ...
test.cpp:5:9: style: struct member 'Struct::unused' is never used. [unusedStructMember]
    int unused;
        ^
```

While I used C++ code in the example it behaves the same for C.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion! I'll give this a try.

Comment: This is somewhat useless in practice because cppcheck is unable to detect unused struct members in C header files even if whole program analysis (`--cppcheck-build-dir`) is enabled.